# Will a device designed for the 2x13 pins of Model A also work on Model B with 2x20 pins?

Tags: gpio, pi-models

Will a device, e.g. this [transciever](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/slice-of-radio-wireless-rf-transciever-for-the-raspberry-pi), that is designed to be placed on the 2x13 pins of a Model A Raspberry also work if used with a 40pin Raspberry, i.e. are the pins that same?

When viewing some pin diagrams of the two it looks like there are some differences but in pther places it says they are compatible.

Comment: There's a bit of a caveat in that the plastic ends of the female header on the module may be thicker than the space between pins -- however, it probably won't be hard to file down as long as you are careful.

Answer (score 3):

Pins 1 to 26 are common to all Pi models apart from revision 1 of the original model B.

```
GPIO       pin  pin    GPIO
3V3         1    2      5V
0/2 (SDA)   3    4      5V
1/3 (SCL)   5    6      0V
4           7    8      14 (TXD)
0V          9   10      15 (RXD)
17 (ce1)   11   12      18 (ce0)
21/27      13   14      0V
22         15   16      23
3V3        17   18      24
10 (MOSI)  19   20      0V
9 (MISO)   21   22      25
11 (SCLK)  23   24      8 (CE0)
0V         25   26      7 (CE1)
           .......
0 (ID_SD)  27   28      1 (ID_SC)
5          29   30      0V
6          31   32      12
13         33   34      0V
19 (miso)  35   36      16 (ce2)
26         37   38      20 (mosi)
0V         39   40      21 (sclk)
```

In the above if the GPIO column has a V it indicates the pin is connected to the power rail and not a GPIO.

Where 2 figures are shown separated by a / the first figure is the GPIO connected on the first revision Pi model B boards.

Comment: So the answer to my question "Will a device that is designed to be placed on the 2x13 pins of a Model A Raspberry also work if used with a 40pin Raspberry" is an unconditional yes?

Comment: Nobody can give an unconditional yes.  Your Pi might be bust, the device might be bust, you might connect it back to front, you might power it with 240 V, you might break something if you force a fit.  As long as you take reasonable care it should work.